# Google Places API results for 0,0 Lat Lng

Tags: geocoding, latitude-longitude, google-places-api, google-places

I'm not sure why Google Places API is returning the following results for lat,lng = 0,0 ... shouldn't it be fetching places at the Prime Meridian and Equator intersection, and not just a smattering of cities whose geocoords are clearly not close to 0,0 like:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.7483170,
               "lng" : -73.9855290
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "2bf00f9f5e2e3e50098fd611f9fde65cdb453f20",
         "name" : "Empire State Building",
         "rating" : 4.40,
         "reference" : "CnRrAAAAtzNwdIo2Dcf4rhroiiyCyJqarCL7FZQvXxvz6vdYda1MYaxmjfwPdd2k_nyyq1c-urcOZ2GIg3r5GqmjtguEQNlKiYu8706vHJKiZCax-COsvbWHS3WBLWiZ3uYoY2wGclP3D-2loob4rNFa_XavERIQaVGvVVfsV3ayD8D9_-dtqhoUmZInS1ufM4ErRz4s76nX5Wr8PUA",
         "types" : [ "amusement_park", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "350 5th Avenue, New York"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 34.0554640,
               "lng" : -118.249760
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "5cf64f5eb238d7e3740c59a49938ceb7c5b08646",
         "name" : "Gedung Konser Walt Disney",
         "rating" : 4.40,
         "reference" : "CnRwAAAAfgumgAs3d8qOytOVUEgMBSbddJ80fSzX7JbsmxHvwZRkto-_tLF1VIgkswR3VRMBRfC5fs4JNcgVEhb2KQbRMFFC1FImwRlSM6igdR5TWpYiP2PlP1tA80SPF8lR_7TNM_fS0GyDM9Y45nE59S-WCxIQKbEIn_MR0ASWWc47N0yx1BoUDbjx_g1pzUAIzfTI7-UcsVdr8n4",
         "types" : [ "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "111 S Grand Ave, Los Angeles"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.7599740,
               "lng" : -73.9800970
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "89dd7f0c82efc14f18954f8abf2925515037927a",
         "name" : "Radio City Music Hall",
         "rating" : 3.90,
         "reference" : "CnRsAAAAz4THB7lZ9nA3Il7YOwfFubKCR91gBo8jHNlXUQWUw7JEliOwoNsvgQOAtECHb7RttpnRFJj2gwMq4aFYR7ndaTlp53rNMpoFp4DDS_EVA1WlioGNqFGEi4vzkQbqetoJ9VN1O9cJg2YJpL7TuR9dNxIQWwsOVjW_tUB5sGlMYSlaSxoUxYYdcSHox7CfUmZ7P0Rc7zV7_e0",
         "types" : [ "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1260 6 Avenue, New York"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 38.8895020,
               "lng" : -77.0353030
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "2598a3577d35a8f9ce6cc12c6c20d59fe3f9d1fc",
         "name" : "Washington Monument",
         "rating" : 3.50,
         "reference" : "CnRqAAAAtAuqKVfxJ_ni_49Wg8THdIjk7sK7C3wVMIjoSVPSriDr6Tht5-RvBScdFB_VasYBMR1BO_TESlyHQfCONNh3c2xjVsUPwFLruSPpKZCgA1gZY5eE3amDsFhjB2gZc2zQatv3dBbcW5HxWwK38KDn2xIQj20Ad9IMHh2A15niVVW-ihoUzwSKPeInBDipmiHe-oX0eS751_c",
         "types" : [ "park", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "2 15th Street Northwest, Washington D.C."
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.7075260,
               "lng" : -74.0111520
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "010cda7c358ae874784ef918d1c19e2643c4fec0",
         "name" : "NYSE Regulation Inc",
         "rating" : 3.40,
         "reference" : "CnRqAAAAR8SX_5aQ60pZEffiLIbXTxoXVCdzpIVleLXseSizaa08ZyAV-6HKFoXP_3eFKBcVewUuTgdxX0JJu8idVtjvF-FJnK5-RWt0jp1K2tB2YwOpwHNI7bXnYxqVEATcyH1Y8ft5SXh2uaqRL-SoKwC2hhIQTpljtBc_hALik0ECJD3syhoUmzoPIYGREYJMw1qA4PbeW9yR7_s",
         "types" : [ "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "11 Wall Street, New York"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 36.1573480,
               "lng" : -115.1483340
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
         "id" : "729e341abb54a12a11d84573d977df0f41acca7b",
         "name" : "Las Vegas Pretty Kittens",
         "rating" : 4.30,
         "reference" : "CnRvAAAA1KMLOeN6uzyj-QGAP5Mqg_qe5IDN3Zl9ID_to_pyaxGD5ERHsLsmvGAT801ST89xdHSXk1Tga950V5RBJX5FGopZ2B7rFIBNDPFxrB9wK4mYgaZiwR-m_j1rdzx9EkEPe3JMEnBZq-Y8djh_V2tX8hIQTk931oTYQPGyVCL1rQQDaRoUzhWJ_Cq1UFvKAhNansZJVO4ipOI",
         "types" : [ "lodging", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "3798 Las Vegas Blvd, Las Vegas"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.829750,
               "lng" : -73.92613799999999
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/stadium-71.png",
         "id" : "4120a48a1c6bae3f896b9022fbe45bbdbb041c8d",
         "name" : "Yankee Stadium",
         "rating" : 4.40,
         "reference" : "CnRlAAAAsHJIlsQHJmkIYUOW_6m1l8th1F5qtG9ULSn6i9-kAc5cjoxRvDmpeqze14ErqEcxVZPT4wLyU_S845VpDzeJH9XeQHFZWUIr_uu8U01xD9VO4TghUfmBikJN5Ap4cn7zf3BPgBnqVcymBMWeOsr0ABIQbNrG__9TSUduj-lSHV8OGBoUW3867le_CNRd-5ZncKMGgu1y-Q4",
         "types" : [ "stadium", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1 East 161st Street, Bronx"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 36.1475610,
               "lng" : -115.155430
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
         "id" : "7a80fe02f232f2f8fb62953d7eca557722b58012",
         "name" : "Stratosphere",
         "rating" : 3.60,
         "reference" : "CnRjAAAAjLLI-i_uFl-t4VGhFXpbA8GOiu5NxFKPvjQVludTJBowR-McYhjy8Xm1sfIi5eDCT4M4nPCJ8Zr-ixYI_lfNVviGAy9qiteA5_KYvlbzVBnDY9Cg2Dl0tjcQeiRy6HoXlXihb_TiOb5pcqQlJyfg_xIQ4HS8Ie0KuGfZxgOBQzBwiBoU2FjrN08mGMZRnFw96ebkGB9iM0c",
         "types" : [ "lodging", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "2000 South Las Vegas Boulevard, Las Vegas"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 36.0989050,
               "lng" : -115.1754280
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
         "id" : "5415e1b4a3f278a0f654cecaefd3a8c9c18de6cf",
         "name" : "Buca di Beppo - Las Vegas - Excalibur",
         "rating" : 3.70,
         "reference" : "CoQBfAAAAH4lqpHGSoEJj1NpWM9G9TFv9wd8h1iupqzjFckBVlqWp3Py0-zg0l2uEIQq_1rFDzVIBa7r4uzKSmbj8x_djw2ytBjwdVZHuzPxNH0B6-OsoXgq5VXh_ej0_TQytprNHXkeO6VEhi5REkjtbzOqrwO4n-LwvZ8jdqGZtE-I8BM_EhC--WZHCmvg4s4AQqyBX8pMGhTZfTcTmEPVKyUIGn0J4EcscR6LTA",
         "types" : [ "lodging", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "3850 Las Vegas Blvd. South, Second Floor, Las Vegas"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 34.1025420,
               "lng" : -118.3416570
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/movies-71.png",
         "id" : "46e0f0dc849234110d70dce04cacefa982f1898a",
         "name" : "Kodak Theatre",
         "rating" : 4.0,
         "reference" : "CnRkAAAA9l1BF_OHV88D0oLmjP0eeB9lvlfSuMoH_Clpk0xN2rprdAs-NVajY82CkWk6q5Xgy_-WaKMadnDFWg1dmvBlM9CSG9YjlEsuGdkGAQ_2JT5BKcQZAsgO-LCInrNGQhHb6UA6EINa_oeWIT5yX2wFgxIQCQYutFUfkTt9lUFGv5Q1qRoUE3TXdS-d8wLXrLijExuCRRS7pKs",
         "types" : [ "movie_theater", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "6801 Hollywood Boulevard Hollywood, CA 90028"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 38.8885120,
               "lng" : -77.0201260
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/museum-71.png",
         "id" : "6233faaa08c8457051ce7a2ae89260885c3d099e",
         "name" : "National Air and Space Museum",
         "rating" : 3.90,
         "reference" : "CoQBcwAAANunAGpqdW9ux0r61QRMDJJVpXbcWfzQXYc9Lfsjo11AwnOT00qvjgNEML24mmTlo-fwxPqAori2FXzCz75nrk5ZthIoY6rUwT2XqMo_1wLdeIYzI8HBTB5d80lMZCDyYPNIyUXK1BQxkDARI-Djcvm0cxcsd5pkM5nKUcALHClREhDw1unCtEDqrdvaCyiwqO5JGhRlEXlguPNDn8-OhkUM-e2zVIfJHQ",
         "types" : [ "museum", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "595 Independence Avenue Southwest, Washington"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.7653850,
               "lng" : -73.9796820
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "ff0ea6469ef95cea73f323b77e18bc2065fb3f3f",
         "name" : "Carnegie Hall",
         "rating" : 3.80,
         "reference" : "CnRjAAAAxCg7QA4KqEWMXOJnLZ4tZj_HefkwzsO_c1yGPbgQZ6hEvbKZymhQ6Fr4wffzF8hpRFr9w6teszOKu-IQW0OqUc4jQaHVz0iErmhMAzIbuX7C_QHmnTn8gVKC4K_Zlp4vDS5AL9-GzhEkj_rYmyg3FhIQ7YW9PNRhxLTkVvi3wBLALxoUiEwWkeBsTM_FrUybFcqpToYbtS0",
         "types" : [ "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "881 7th Ave, New York"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.7714720,
               "lng" : -122.4686720
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "d0f545120ffb6baec5da1ab9e5a9c19f49115dc5",
         "name" : "Fine Arts Museums of San Francisco: Facility Rentals",
         "rating" : 4.10,
         "reference" : "CpQBiwAAAL6id9WjmuDsGHBq1ikNCGmYv1i652crIWcDwPNOMazjrCYvde35uVNQIsdzRDcEBIEXgzIm3Vi9CmUPLevsigYOAd3TQ61z5huCv_53jSlITWzcKsaOa_ZAQQPZyMpYPwhkxnYESU-4GFzzoLFzH1-afqCKcwrFAauKCDcTvwy2qfYPXfio1grIEKfBln83qRIQrmVEtNeLqO5n9WOjjXhJMhoUfZkJU9kN8CAIOY__1Y3syoPB_1k",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "museum", "food", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "50 Hagiwara Tea Garden Drive, San Francisco"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.6709750,
               "lng" : -73.96363599999999
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/museum-71.png",
         "id" : "50536f2341830cb033e6342fb2e123d88fb5262b",
         "name" : "Brooklyn Museum",
         "rating" : 4.30,
         "reference" : "CnRmAAAAurnWOaSKJ3xC5JCHa0RpCbJ4o36w6z2FDWePJNM2wPhvlp9PyyLNe_REHiA82IlTTaoUKXSJRecUr-CW88YfzNsEZ20GQFXm21PKkgrrF1vP0NL6S-wb4xbr_k5vNnZgW1_5rVf7AsPg_02xRDc2BBIQRIERe2yg8Xi94SOFussv3hoU1ym_ci8XQ7W1US6tdpOTvtMMDCw",
         "types" : [ "museum", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "200 Eastern Parkway, Brooklyn"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 41.881320,
               "lng" : -87.674280
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/stadium-71.png",
         "id" : "99dbf0f7af6e6fd7fe9f48b5cfd5d9374d40eee7",
         "name" : "Madison & United Center (1900 W)",
         "rating" : 4.60,
         "reference" : "CoQBdwAAAIwXyy6eDjcW_4Bub5XvmGHiqMJ-Stl1QIYLE9y7i2vC1TCCAUXGYB9y-ydP4rs7A3YP5ux5Eh5dfWpczrUEIz7FFhBXHCcu7mKFGx8ifLXTg6NWjLtXGSBMk5UOkuMlQ759B4UGufhgLNCPXdrPqO6kTMZG8VQ1tenNlPLPtkWrEhB2WMI2FjYGBmlCHBYayIFGGhT2uist4FA0sRJmBj3o4iALDgBT9Q",
         "types" : [ "stadium", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1901 West Madison Street, Chicago"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 36.1214190,
               "lng" : -115.1704240
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
         "id" : "8fdee88bfe0bc1d70eaf2a1c8528934528344298",
         "name" : "The Venetian",
         "rating" : 4.10,
         "reference" : "CnRjAAAAMATHKiVvbWVf4PLp8RwYQB_pHCu_3Fua1MQ7Gl5B1xNDHU9WkICPeu__TGD5Hfgb47b9V6bCxEkgLFbi21dwOThtDjtby4tDH2HnL7iba6_CxYrgMOrP-WOuh4HMPqCU5Fu5Tm2mttHLgNQ3H2eCKBIQ99KyfeOqL8Ke8eF_IQWehxoUsjo-AknTVGd_LpuAIcBlKFtw0LY",
         "types" : [ "lodging", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "3355 Las Vegas Boulevard South, Las Vegas"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.8647670,
               "lng" : -73.9317990
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/museum-71.png",
         "id" : "8edf774a665aeb294a6d6cf8df4405f4824f7e4f",
         "name" : "The Cloisters",
         "rating" : 3.90,
         "reference" : "CnRkAAAAoXh2hlwgjHoK57WLbYJXZylMK2E96FRHa_TzNBEq4vxTUHrq_eguI58Yo0iQRBtFX3ro5U8OdwzMreDpgUTnVFMPRCzxWyshdL-tCaEjIWK-3VpdCHh4imG3x_fjLfqgFi4Ndf48gctZhrOg-0RNdhIQnpmnyP-W9TN1HmvwTeNtUBoUQ2BQXpiGHWltpzK1zKGdq8FIYzk",
         "types" : [ "museum", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "99 Margaret Corbin Drive, New York"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 38.8959010,
               "lng" : -77.0552390
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "66763890699cdd158cff72bffe0f7ab48c755a43",
         "name" : "The John F. Kennedy Center for the Performing Arts",
         "rating" : 4.50,
         "reference" : "CpQBiQAAAK5sBdti2mRClLvnnl7-P_sAs0ptzxUvT4YWZ9bYP4wyIPHzvSv2D3DAhx_tK7g_jsKM7qnbIhXrJW_9Bb7XU9XexgIsm6rSRkTGuN70JRy5d4ztsl8ZVaYBjSewb0AS98TB84E5Xx-l9IsKhx3hypgCFI5u-CuC6vlmjVNdR-u-cgHTx1B5HTZpkTXIm5muqxIQ2lINhfQKQsl6YzCKMzLGNxoUMxrl7OJKpqEBCRxUu7A1GrsiWto",
         "types" : [ "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "2700 F Street Northwest, Washington"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.782820,
               "lng" : -73.9591570
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/museum-71.png",
         "id" : "aa09742d854b00192daed833e2a56750587e8185",
         "name" : "Solomon R. Guggenheim Museum",
         "rating" : 3.10,
         "reference" : "CoQBcgAAAOrwNzRmsnbhv193CwDcwpw0PlTBBEGoYm6ksdTk5Ro73hmIJnRsOqXHvfKrDoXCLC_MHwW9gjEEp_t789Afn_sRj8dn1IlQJ8TontYBEf-pLXmNNt104Y14fAsHykQ2JyifjuUoCsykKt_E04AIM2A1H939uAMJPc6R0VEgaZNYEhBCqGL-r9yCh4zZjLqafPekGhRE0aNDwrGBz9XYHMmeudjhFjlsIQ",
         "types" : [ "museum", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1071 5th Avenue, New York"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.8042110,
               "lng" : -73.96284199999999
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_general-71.png",
         "id" : "b7f595c8882d8b5c347f124cb06be5a18ba794d9",
         "name" : "Cathedral Church of St. John the Divine",
         "rating" : 4.0,
         "reference" : "CoQBfgAAAFuadX23-mmKRnASp9ylUzW0Ghz3d8CuqZ55tX2T4BrODOTVDpOZn55xKqjuemfE-7hrdYOfaLff4RKkEzCkbhTR5UX8iGDCcMHQq2O7aWoqA2tsa5dCBkta8eTy-Bpry8zf2iaRVEZbx1Wfq2Xg59vvu07bryUX4sPVNRO5wKkyEhAXHfHMMaiMKjkvhezqXDk1GhQMHvS79gfVmdb2EQYKWL3df6Y-ag",
         "types" : [ "church", "place_of_worship", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1047 Amsterdam Avenue, New York"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

API doc [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)

Call this url to get above results:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=0,0&radius=5&sensor=false&key=[insert key here]`

Anyone know why it's giving the above results?

---

Oddly enough, I've been to all of those places... I wonder if these 0,0 results are session or IP-address based...

Answer (score 1):

This must be a database-error, I get the same results for 0/0.

I was playing around a little bit, for 0.1/0.1 I got this funny results(note that the markers are really at 0.1/0.1 ) 
[**http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/aZrvs/33/show/**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/aZrvs/33/show/) (*I reported the wrong markers, maybe they will be removed soon*)

Places from Brasil, Mexico, Belgium, Germany and  China now are placed in the gulf of guinea ^^

When you click on the markers and then on "Details" you'll see that those errors also  occure on the official google-places-pages.

Comment: I wonder how you report these errors, as it seems the only way to report is if you can find its places page.

Comment: The places-pages are present, you'll find them when you click on a marker and then on "Details". I also reported the 0/0 issue of this topic, maybe they give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the Google Places API. I have submitted it internally.

For future bugs in the Google Places API you can submit them through the Google Maps API Issue tracker as a 'Places API - Bug':
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Bug